# Leetcode 191: mod 10 versus mod 2

Tags: bit-manipulation, modulo

I am working through Leetcode's problem 191: Number of 1 Bits, and am confused as to a certain aspect of the solution. Here is the question:

*Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of '1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).*

And here is my (correct) solution:

```
func hammingWeight(num uint32) int {
    c := 0
    for num > 0{
        if num%2==1{
            c++
        }
        num/=2
    }
    return c
}
```

My question is twofold:

1. Does the program read input such as *0001101* as a binary number, and if so, why? I assumed that for a uint32 parameter, it would read it in decimal by default.
2. When shifting over to the right, why do we use /2 instead of /10?

I am still trying to wrap my head around the basic bit manipulation stuff, so this is still confusing me. If you take *0001101* and int divide it by 2, you would get 550, not 110. But if you take the same number and int divide it by 10, you would get 110. Why is /2 correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Does the program read input` This function doesn't read input at all. `When shifting over to the right, why do we use /2` Because numbers are stored in binary, not decimal.

Comment: You're mixing binary and decimal all over the place. Think in what notation is writen each number and do the math again.

Comment: Dividing the binary number `0001101` (dec `13`) by the decimal integer `2` would result in the integer decimal `6`, not `550`. You're really confused about the relationship between binary and decimal representations of numbers. You should find a good online tutorial.

Comment: @KenWhite I think I see what you mean, but I am still confused as to why _0001101_ would be read as dec 13 instead of dec 1101. Because if I write fmt.Println(1101 / 2), 1101 is read as 'one-thousand-one-hundred-and-one', not 13.

Comment: Because `1101` is decimal. `00001101` is understood as binary, because the compiler sees it begins with a leading `0`. Numbers in decimal notation don't have leading zeroes. The value `01101` is also decimal `13`, again because of the leading zero.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah, I understand now — thank you!